# AVAudioPlayer Leak and Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, avaudioplayer

I want to play multiple audio files (`.WAV`) using `IBAction` and `AVAudioPlayer`. Unfortunatelly the sound plays but if I play the sound many times, my application crashes. Can you help me?

Here's my code.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    NSString        *Path;
}

- (IBAction)Sound1;
- (IBAction)Sound2;
- (IBAction)Sound3;
- (IBAction)Sound4;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

AVAudioPlayer *Media;

- (IBAction)Sound1
{
    Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound1" ofType:@"wav"];
    Media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path] error:NULL];
    [Media setDelegate:self];
    [Media play];
}

- (IBAction)Sound2
{
    Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound2" ofType:@"wav"];
    Media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path] error:NULL];
    [Media setDelegate:self];
    [Media play];
}

- (IBAction)Sound3
{
    Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound3" ofType:@"wav"];
    Media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path] error:NULL];
    [Media setDelegate:self];
    [Media play];
}

- (IBAction)Sound4
{
    Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound4" ofType:@"wav"];
    Media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path] error:NULL];
    [Media setDelegate:self];
    [Media play];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [player release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [Media Release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things that look wrong in your code:

(1). There are no method Release, `[Media Release]` should be `[Media release]`;

(2). If you play Sound2 while Sound1 is still playing, you leak Media instance:

```
Media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:...
```

This allocates new player and overwrites old one without releasing it first;

(3). It is usually bad idea to release calling object in delegate;

(4). I'd also suggest to rename `Media` to `media` and `Path` to `path`.

So playing action should look like this:

```
- (IBAction)playSound1
{
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound1" ofType:@"wav"];
    media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [media play];
    [media release];
}
```